# Free notepad that can show a ruler for Number of characters

Tags: windows

I use notepad2, it's excellent, but It cannot show a ruler which can give the number of characters on each line (I want to count them to do some fix-length export).

Do you know one ?

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Comment: I too prefer Notepad2. You could always just [email Florian] to request that be added. I find he is amenable to bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: @Luke, it already is:   *are there any free text editors that have a character-ruler?*   That’s not (just) a software-recommendation; it’s a technical question.

Comment: @Synetech Alright, I stand corrected. It sounded like a product recommendation to me

Comment: @Luke, well yes, in that he is trying to identify a software that has a specific feature, but that’s quite different from *what is a cheap program that can do this?* or *what kind of computer should I get to play that game?*

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ with a Plugin has it I belive.

Answer (score 0):

[E - Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/):

> E is a new text editor for Windows, with powerful editing features and
>   quite a few unique abilities. It makes manipulating text fast and
>   easy, and lets you focus on your writing by automating all the manual
>   work. You can extend it in any language, and by supporting TextMate
>   bundles, it allows you to tap into a huge and active community

Comment: Hi seems great editor but it's not free ;)

Comment: It has a 30 Days Free Trial.